# Exemple using BCryptDeriveKeyPBKDF2 from MSDN

Tags: c++, cryptoapi

I don't find some simple exemple using BCryptDeriveKeyPBKDF2 function.
I need to get key with PBKDF2 algorithm. I think it is symple action but i find very diffucult ways. I using CryptoApi Windows and i need get key.

Show me please how can i use this function to get key BCryptDeriveKeyPBKDF2 ?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bcrypt/nf-bcrypt-bcryptderivekeypbkdf2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also had a hard time finding a simple example. I was finally able to create this:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "bcrypt.lib")
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

    std::string password = "This is the password that will be encrypted";
    std::string salt = "EncryptionSalt";
    NTSTATUS Status;
    BYTE DerivedKey[64];

    BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE handle;
    Status = BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider(&handle, BCRYPT_SHA512_ALGORITHM, NULL, BCRYPT_ALG_HANDLE_HMAC_FLAG);

    if (Status != 0)
    {
        std::cout << "BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider exited with error message " << Status;
        goto END;
    }

    Status = BCryptDeriveKeyPBKDF2(handle, (BYTE*)password.data(), password.length(), (BYTE*)salt.data(), 8, 2048, DerivedKey, 64, 0);

    if (Status != 0)
    {
        std::cout << "BCryptDeriveKeyPBKDF2 exited with error message " << Status;
        goto END;
    }

    else
        std::cout << "Operation completed successfully. Your encrypted key is in variable DerivedKey.";

    BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider(handle, 0);

END:;

}
```